How to use all CPU cores in Raspberry Pi for mount.davfs process
I've configured a drive map using mount.davfs in Raspberry Pi 4 working OK. We can access the mounted drive and see and use all files. The issue we are facing is that when the usage of the volume is high, the CPU process for mount.davfs is 100% but the monitoring is showing that only 25% of the CPU is used, so mount.davfs is using only one core.
Can we enforce this process to use all 4 cores?
Thanks
